# Order by rand() on a large mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, random

My site is very slow with because of this mysql query.

```
SELECT content.*,
       (SELECT content_views.views FROM content_views WHERE content_views.content = content.record_num) as views ,
       (SELECT images.filename FROM images WHERE images.record_num = content.thumbnail) AS thumbfile
FROM content WHERE enabled = 1  $filterAnd
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT $from,$max_results
```

I know the best way is to use it like this:

```
SELECT name
  FROM random AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM random)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

But i am using multiple mysql tables i have no idea how i can use my query like this someone that can help me ?

Thank you

edit:

I have tried:

```
SELECT content.*,
       (SELECT content_views.views FROM content_views WHERE content_views.content = content.record_num) as views ,
       (SELECT images.filename FROM images WHERE images.record_num = content.thumbnail) AS thumbfile
FROM content AS r1 JOIN
     (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(record_num) FROM content)) AS id) AS r2
WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

but now i get the error: Unknown table 'content'

Answer (score 0):

This code selects one random row from **content** table.

```
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    content AS r1
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT 
                    MAX(id)
                FROM
                    content WHERE enabled = 1 $filterAnd)) AS id
    ) AS r2
WHERE
    r1.id >= r2.id AND r1.enabled=1 AND $filterAnd
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1) randomTable
```

Now you need to think about this query as an table with name `randomTable` fields as in `content` table. Now you can SELECT from it, JOIN it, to do all what you need. Pay attention to `$filterAnd` - I used it twice. This will work only if `$filterAnd` contain conditions related to `content` table.

Answer (score 0):

You have given the table `content` an alias called `r1`.  You then need to use that alias for references to that particular table:

```
SELECT r1.*,
       (SELECT cv.views
        FROM content_views cv
        WHERE cv.content = r1.record_num
       ) as views,
       (SELECT i.filename
        FROM images i
        WHERE i.record_num = r1.thumbnail
       ) AS thumbfile
FROM content r1 JOIN
     (SELECT RAND() * (SELECT MAX(record_num) FROM content) AS id
     ) r2
WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This version has table aliases for many of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the suggestions so far assume an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id with no holes.  If that does not apply, see [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) for that solution, plus 7 more.